# Java add SOAP header without xmlns attribute

Tags: java, soap, http-headers

I need to add a Header to a SOAP request and I do it with the following code:

```
INotificationManagement notification = host.getBasicHttpBindingINotificationManagement();

    WSBindingProvider bp = (WSBindingProvider)notification;
    bp.setOutboundHeaders(Headers.create(newQName("bob:sessionId"),sessionId));
```

And I get:

```
<S:Header><bob:sessionId xmlns="">aosidaosi</bob:sessionId></S:Header>
```

The problem is I don't want the xmlns attribute to be there...it should simply be `<bob:sessionId>`
I tried all the new QName methods and still it puts the xmlns attribute.

Is there anyway to make a header without the xmlns attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare "bob"'s namespace somewhere, this is a must. You can do it either directly in the node (as in your question) or somewhere in parent nodes:

```
<S:Header xmlns:bob="bob namespace">
  <bob:sessionId>aosidaosi</bob:sessionId>
</S:Header>
```

or even higher, at envelope level

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" xmlns:bob="bob namespace">
  <S:Header>
    <bob:sessionId>aosidaosi</bob:sessionId>
    ...
  </S:Header>
....
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: How can I add xmlns:bob to the S:Header?

Comment: @doubter, as `javax.xml.soap.SOAPHeader` implements `org.w3c.dom.Element`, I believe you can do it via `setAttribute` or `setAttributeNS` methods.

Comment: I can't do .setAttribute on Headers.create(...).setAttribute and I only have SOAPHeader as an interface. Am I missing somehting?